# Is this a type of Flutter installation error in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

I have downloaded and installed Flutter plugin/dart programming in Android studio but it does does not show dart program codes. Why? Any solution?

I was expecting flutter dart codes in new flutter project at Android Studio

[image]

Comment: You need to create a new project using flutter as the technology. After instaling the flutter plugin on android studio a option to create a new flutter project should be available on the new project options

Answer (score 0):

- After you create a new flutter project

  You must goto **Project** section and **lib** folder to find dart
  codes

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: in my case there is no lib folder inside project folder

Comment: try to create a fresh new project or try `flutter create newprojectname` in android studio terminal to create new flutter project using command

Comment: refer this for setup doc: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio